# Seek method not working Flutter Just Audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am working on a basic audio streaming app. Everything is working fine Play/Pause , Skip the song... The only problem that i have is to go forward in a Song.

My goal is to have a button to skip 10seconds of the music.

Here is the class AudioManager that i am using :

```
class AudioManager {
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;

  String lastBeatType = "";
  Data data  = Data(id: "",channelTitle: "",title: "",link:"");
  AudioManager({required this.lastBeatType});

  void dispose() {
  _audioPlayer.dispose();
  } 
  void initAudio() async {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    
  
  }

  void play() {
    
    _audioPlayer.play();

  }

  void pause() {
    _audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  
  void goForward() async{
 
    await _audioPlayer.seek(const Duration(seconds: _audioPlayer.position.inSeconds + 10) );



  }

  void goBackward() {
    _audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: _audioPlayer.position.inSeconds - 10));
  }



  //Function getting the buffers of the songs
   getBeat(String type) async {
    print("Entering Get Beat");
    lastBeatType = type;

    AudioManager _audioManager = AudioManager(lastBeatType: type);


    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:5000/beat?type=$type"));
    print("Response has been getted");
    
  
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final songdata = jsonDecode(response.body);
      _audioPlayer.setUrl("http://localhost:5000/audio?videoId=${songdata["id"]}");
    
    }
  
    return response.bodyBytes;

    
  }
```

The function goForward/goBackward are the one that i am using.

But when i press the button here is the error i have

`Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 0`

Any help would be very appreciate !

Comment: @RyanHeise sorry to @ you but maybe you could help me dealing with this issue?

Comment: If there is a plugin issue, you should open an issue on GitHub. I don't think this question can be answered without a reproduction project which is what you would provide when submitting a bug report.